# CSV to Nested Python Dict

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, nested

i'd like to import certain columns in this csv into a nested python dict:

```
Name, Type, ID, Job, Height
Adam, Man, asmith, factory, 5
Ben, Man, bjones, mine, 6
Jamie, Woman, jbarnes, bank, 5.5
```

output:

```
dict1 = { asmith: {Name:Adam, Type:Man, Height:5},
          bjones, {Name:Ben, Type:Man, Height:6},
          jbarnes:, {Name:Jamie,Type:Woman, Height:5.5} }
```

Comment: **forgot to mention:  the headers are on the 2nd row & is there a specific way to select columns to use (sometimes I want to exclude columns - this ex i'd like to exclude job)**

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `DictReader` from `csv` for this:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = DictReader(csvfile)
    result = {row[' ID'] : row for row in reader}
```

Now `result` will be a dictionary that maps `ID`s to dictionaries. The dictionary will contain the `'ID'` as well. Now `result` will be:

```
{' bjones': {'Name': 'Ben', ' Type': ' Man', ' Height': ' 6', ' ID': ' bjones', ' Job': ' mine'}, ' jbarnes': {'Name': 'Jamie', ' Type': ' Woman', ' Height': ' 5.5', ' ID': ' jbarnes', ' Job': ' bank'}, ' asmith': {'Name': 'Adam', ' Type': ' Man', ' Height': ' 5', ' ID': ' asmith', ' Job': ' factory'}}
```

As we can see the values are not stripped: these contain spaces on the left and the right. We can process these as follows:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = DictReader(csvfile)
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
        row = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in row.items()}
        result[row.pop('ID')] = row
```

This will remove the `ID` key from the dictionaries as well. Now the answer is:

```
>>> result
{'jbarnes': {'Name': 'Jamie', 'Height': '5.5', 'Job': 'bank', 'Type': 'Woman'}, 'bjones': {'Name': 'Ben', 'Height': '6', 'Job': 'mine', 'Type': 'Man'}, 'asmith': {'Name': 'Adam', 'Height': '5', 'Job': 'factory', 'Type': 'Man'}}
```

**EDIT**: In case you want to ignore the first line, you can call `next(..)` on the file handler first:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile)
    reader = DictReader(csvfile)
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
        row = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in row.items()}
        result[row.pop('ID')] = row
```

Comment: I would suggest using `row.pop('ID')` to remove it from the dictionary.